# assigning a subset of data.table rows and columns by join

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to do something similar but different enough from what's described here:
[Update subset of data.table based on join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720923/update-subset-of-data-table-based-on-join)

Specifically, I'd like to assign to matching key values (`person_id` is a key in both tables) column values from table control.  `CI` is the column index.  The statement below says `'with=F' was not used`.  when I delete those parts, it also doesn't work as expected.  Any suggestions?

To rephrase: I'd like to set the subset of flatData that corresponds to control FROM control.

```
flatData[J(eval(control$person_id)), ci, with=F] = control[, ci, with=F]
```

To give a reproducible example using classic R:

```
x = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, key = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
y = data.frame(a = c(2, 5), b = c(11, 2), key = c('a', 'b'))

colidx = match(c('a', 'b'), colnames(y))

x[x$key %in% y$key, colidx] = y[, colidx]
```

As an aside, someone please explain how to easily assign SETS of columns without using indices!  Indices and data.table are a marriage made in hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:=` operator along with the join simultaneously as follows:

First prepare data:

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.0
setDT(x)            ## converts DF to DT by reference
setDT(y)
setkey(x, key)      ## set key column
setkey(y, key)
```

Now the one-liner:

```
x[y, c("a", "b") := list(i.a, i.b)]
```

`:=` modifies by reference (in-place). The rows to modify are provided by the indices computed from the join in `i`.

`i.a` and `i.b` are the column names `data.table` internally generates for easy access to `i`'s columns when both `x` and `i` have identical column names, when performing a join of the form `x[i]`.

HTH

PS: In your example `y`'s columns a and b are of type numeric and `x`'s are of type integer and therefore you'll get a warning when run on your data, that the types dint match and therefore a coercion had to take place.

Comment: Dear @Arun, while I like your answer in general, it does have the problem of enumerating the set of columns explicitly, which I said I was loth to do - my column sets are very large.  There's a reason why I used colidx :(

Comment: Maybe there's a way to use lists for this purpose?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22871741/559784) for construction and usage of `eval(parse(..))` type expressions or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22768747/559784) for another approach - construction of expression with symbols.