# How to merge tables and fill the empty cells in the mean time in R?

Tags: r, join

Assume there are two tables a and b.

Table a:

```
ID AGE
 1  20
 2  empty
 3  40
 4  empty
```

Table b:

```
ID AGE
 2  25
 4  45
 5  60
```

How to merge the two table in **R** so that the resulting table becomes:

```
ID AGE
 1  20
 2  25
 3  40
 4  45
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `NA` on every position in the first table where you want to use the second table's age numbers you can use `rbind` and `na.omit`.

*Example*

```
x <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4), AGE=c(20,NA,40,NA))
y <- data.frame(ID=c(2,4,5), AGE=c(25,45,60))
na.omit(rbind(x,y))
```

Results in what you're after (although unordered and I assume you just forgot ID 5)

```
ID AGE
1  20
3  40
2  25
4  45
5  60
```

#### EDIT

If you want to merge two different `data.frames`'s and keep the columns its a different thing. You can use `merge` to achieve this.

Here are two data frames with different columns:

```
x <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4), AGE=c(20,NA,40,NA), COUNTY=c(1,2,3,4))
y <- data.frame(ID=c(2,4,5), AGE=c(25,45,60), STATE=c('CA','CA','IL'))
```

Add them together into one `data.frame`

```
res <- merge(x, y, by='ID', all=T)
```

giving us

```
ID AGE.x COUNTY AGE.y STATE
 1    20      1    NA  <NA>
 2    NA      2    25    CA
 3    40      3    NA  <NA>
 4    NA      4    45    CA
 5    NA     NA    60    IL
```

Then massage it into the form we want

```
idx <- which(is.na(res$AGE.x))                     # find missing rows in x
res$AGE.x[idx] <- res$AGE.y[idx]                   # replace them with y's values
names(res)[agrep('AGE\\.x', names(res))] <- 'AGE'  # rename merged column AGE.x to AGE
subset(res, select=-AGE.y)                         # dump the AGE.y column
```

Which gives us

```
ID AGE COUNTY STATE
 1  20      1  <NA>
 2  25      2    CA
 3  40      3  <NA>
 4  45      4    CA
 5  60     NA    IL
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Another question is: If table a and table b both have another column which is not shared in common, is there anyway to do the merge, fill the empty cells,  and keep both extra columns in the resulting table? For example, table a has an extra column of STATE, table b has an extra column of COUNTY? Thanks!

Comment: Sure but then this wouldn't work. Ill add an edit with another solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(a), ID)[b, AGE:= i.AGE][]
#   ID AGE
#1:  1  20
#2:  2  25
#3:  3  40
#4:  4  45
```

#### data

```
a <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4), AGE=c(20,NA,40,NA))
b <- data.frame(ID=c(2,4,5), AGE=c(25,45,60))
```

Comment: Provide setting key functionality to `setDT`directly.

Comment: @Arun You meant something like `setDT(a, key=ID)`, but not yet implemented ?

Comment: Right. `setDT(dat, col1, col2, ...)` and probably `setDTv(dat, key = c("col1", "col2"))`...

Comment: @Arun That looks more convenient

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the help! I am just wondering about the meaning of "AGE := i.AGE". I didn't find corresponding explanations in the help file of data.table package.

Comment: @xyin  May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976527/assigning-a-subset-of-data-table-rows-and-columns-by-join

Answer (score 1):

The package in the other answer will work. Here is a dirty hack if you don't want to use the package:

```
x$AGE[is.na(x$AGE)] <- y$AGE[y$ID %in% x$ID]
> x
  ID AGE
1  1  20
2  2  25
3  3  40
4  4  45
```

But, I would use the package to avoid the clunky code.